# What is the Ideal image dimensions for better OCR by google vision?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, azure-cognitive-services, google-vision, image-preprocessing

I have been using google vision OCR for a while now. And I have observed that the OCR result varies with image dimension. Say for example an image with dimension 720 x 1280 gives a better result than 360 x 720. And it sometimes does worse the other way.

I have experienced the same with Microsoft's OCR API.

So is there an ideal image dimension that always gives a good OCR result? How does the image dimensions affect the OCR result?

Answer (score 1):

Please reference here for that information: [Google Supported images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files#image_sizing)

FACE_DETECTION  **1600 x 1200** Distance between eyes is most important

LANDMARK_DETECTION  **640 x 480**

LOGO_DETECTION  **640 x 480**

LABEL_DETECTION **640 x 480**

TEXT_DETECTION and DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION  **1024 x 768**  OCR requires more 
resolution to detect characters

SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION   **640 x 480**

[Google Supported images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0O6O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link below, not only the resolution, the aspect ratio is also a factor
 https://www.mlreader.com/prepare-image-for-google-vision-api